# Error when using "Collect_List()" function in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, tez

Whenever I run function "collect_list" on Hive, it always throws an error:

```
Query ID = xxxxx
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Failed to get session
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

Here's the example:

Data:

```
id    value
1       A
1       B
2       C
3       D
```

I run the query on hive's terminal and here's my query:

```
SELECT id, collect_list(value) FROM something GROUP BY id;
```

I want the result like this:

```
id    value
1       A, B
2       C
3       D
```

Do I need to configure something before using collect_list function?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should be grouping by id

SELECT collect_list(value) FROM something group by id;

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that. I'll edit the query to make it clear

Comment: do you see the same issue using mapred engine?

Answer (score 0):

Collect_list uses ArrayList, so the data will be kept in the same order they were added, to do that, you need to use SORT BY clause in a subquery, don't use ORDER BY, it will cause your query to execute in a non-distributed way.

```
SELECT id, COLLECT_LIST(value)
FROM (SELECT * FROM something SORT BY id, value DESC) x
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, when I tried to use SORT BY, the error still the same. I don't know what is wrong in here